# Rewrite the sum of the products by interpretation

Tags: combinatorics

By interpreting what the following sum is counting and then counting the same object in a different way, rewrite the following sum as a product of two terms (without any sum):
$\sum\limits_{k=m}^n$ $n\choose k$ $k\choose m$, where $0 ≤ m ≤ n$.

What I have so far: We know that $n\choose k$ is the number of ways of selecting $k$ distinct objects from $n$ distinct objects without regard for order. This is the same for $k\choose m$. We also know that if there are $n\choose k$ ways of doing something and $k\choose m$ ways of doing another thing, then there are   $n\choose k$ $\times$ $k\choose m$ ways of performing both actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Think of it this way. You start with $n$ white balls numbered $1$ through $n$. You pick $k$ of them (for some $k\ge m$) and paint them red. Then you pick $m$ of the red balls and paint a gold star on each of them. In the end you have $m$ red balls with gold stars, $k-m$ red balls without stars, and $n-k$ white balls. In effect you’ve simply divided the $n$ balls into three categories, one of which contains exactly $m$ balls, while either of the other two may be empty. Thus, you could just as well do it by first picking $m$ of the white balls to paint red and adorn with gold stars, and then picking an arbitrary subset of the remaining white balls to paint red. Can you think of a product of two expressions, not involving summations, that gives the number of ways to do this?

Comment: This is a good analogy, but I still don't see it. Sorry.

Comment: @EmaLee: How many ways are there to choose $m$ of the $n$ balls? How many ways are there to choose an arbitrary subset of the other $n-m$ balls?

Comment: Well, there are $m\choose n$ ways to choose $m$ of the $n$ balls. And then the number of ways to choose a subset of $m-n$ is cardinality of the power set of $m-n$ (?).

Comment: @EmaLee: Your binomial coefficient is upside down: you want $\binom{n}m$. How many subsets does a set of $n-m$ things have?

Comment: It is $2^{n-m}$ right? And so the answer is just $n\choose m$ $\times$ $2^{n-m}$?

Comment: @EmaLee: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @EmaLee: You’re welcome!